# How do I make timer change a sprite every second without using code that's redundant?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, timer, sprite

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase question so sorry if this is confusing. Anyways for context I'm making a sort of minesweeper type of game in unity and one of the things the original game had was a timer. [Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99AMo.png). I want to copy that sort of thing, and while I do have code that works, it's honestly kind of redundant here's what I have .

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timer = 0;
    public bool isStop = false;
    public Image scoreCount;
    public Sprite[] numbersprite;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        timer = 0;
        isStop = true;
    }
```

Ignore all the stuff on the top.

```cs
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(!isStop)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if(timer >= 1f)
            {
                scoreCount.sprite = numbersprite[1];
            }
            if(timer >= 2f)
            {
                scoreCount.sprite = numbersprite[2];
            }
            if(timer >= 3f)
            {
                scoreCount.sprite = numbersprite[3];
            }
            if(timer >= 4f)
            {
                scoreCount.sprite = numbersprite[4];
            }
            if(timer >= 5f)
            {
                scoreCount.sprite = numbersprite[5];
            }
            if(timer >= 6f)
            {
                scoreCount.sprite = numbersprite[6];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to make it so that it both displays a specific sprite after a certain amount of time has based but also not have to resort to using any of this. Is there any way I can make this work?
If you want some more information I can give you that.

Comment: I want to caution you from falling into the trap of over-using coroutines as many of the solutions here are pushing. Coroutines are very useful tools, but relying on InvokeRepeating and coroutines to manage time between frames detaches your in-game timer from the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is the ultimate solution to the problem and can support sprite indefinitely. It is also fully optimized. Just put the sprites 0 to 9 in the first list and the images in the second list respectively.

```cs
public Sprite[] spriteNumbers = new Sprite[10]; // fill with numbers

public List<Image> spriteFieds; // set Images Based on a unit of tens of hundreds
public void Start() => InvokeRepeating(nameof(SyncTimer), 0f, 1f);
public void SyncTimer()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < spriteFieds.Count; i++)
    {
        var index = (int) (Time.time / Mathf.Pow(10, i) % 10);
        spriteFieds[i].sprite = spriteNumbers[index];
    }
}
```

---

### How to make Stop Timer?

Here I created a standalone timer field and you can stop the step timer by pressing the <kbd>Space</kbd> key. You can also reset the timer with the <kbd>R</kbd> key, for example.

```cs
public Sprite[] spriteNumbers = new Sprite[10]; // fill with numbers

public List<Image> spriteFieds; // set timer Fields

public bool isStop;
public float timer;
public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) isStop = !isStop;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        timer = 0;
        SyncTimer();
    }
    if (!isStop)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        SyncTimer();
    }
}
public void SyncTimer()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < spriteFieds.Count; i++)
    {
        var index = (int) (timer / Mathf.Pow(10, i) % 10);
        spriteFieds[i].sprite = spriteNumbers[index];
    }
}
```

---

### The Timer Result:

[image]

Comment: Your solution detaches the in-game timer from the display. While the display may indicate a "timer", it will not actually accurately reflected an accessible in-game timer. If points or hi-scores are determined by the time, this solution will not work.

Comment: @ErikOverflow It does not make much difference. You just need to replace the timer with a score source. The main issue in this question is the coordination of sprite with integer.

Comment: Additionally, if you're only invoking once per second, you run the risk of frame lag causing a desync. InvokeRepeating does not have a built-in catchup behaviour. This is not a place where overoptimization is needed, as the complexity is O(1)

Comment: The final solution is also because this code can cover an infinite number of digits. I also personally upvoted you for this purpose maybe u don't know. If you pay attention, `invokeRepeat` is also written outside the body of the Sync function. This means that the user can sync it with the desired event.

Comment: InvokeRepeat is only as accurate as the framerate. It is much less accurate than the native timer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have 10 sprites for you numbers 0-9.

numberSprite[0] would hold the sprite for "0", numberSprite[1] would hole "1", etc.

Let's say the timer is at 319.8f seconds on the back end. You would want 3 sprites to display: 3, 1, 9.

To do this, you'll need to break your timer value and sprite into the hundredths, tenths, and seconds individually. You could do this:

```
    int timerInt = (int)Mathf.floor(timer); //Get the int value of the timer

    int hundredth = (timerInt/100) % 10; // (319/100) => 3 ... (3 % 10) => 3
    scoreCountHundredths.sprite = numberSprite[hundredth];

    int tenth = (timerInt /10) % 10; //(319/10) => 31 ... (31 % 10) => 1
    scoreCountTenths.sprite = numberSprite[tenth];

    int second = timerInt % 10; // (319 % 10) => 9
    scoreCountSeconds.sprite = numberSprite[second];
```

With the above code, your timer should correctly update to any number between 000-999 requiring only 10 sprites uploaded. Additionally, it will automatically loop if your timer goes above 999 due to the modulo (%) logic.

***Warning. Coroutines or InvokeRepeating may be a trap here:***
Coroutines can be used to track the time between updating the sprites, but you'll likely be wanting to tie this display directly to the in-game time. relying on coroutines to update the sprite de-couples the in-game timer from the display, as they do not have built-in catchup behaviour. If your frames are slightly delayed or lag at all, you run the risk of the time running slower when using coroutines or InvokeRepeating.

Comment: Are you the original poster @KiynL ?

Comment: I might be doing something wrong but this didn't work for me, one of the problems I'm having is that it can't convert a float into an int in the timerInt section up on the top.

Comment: I was missing the implicit (int) declarator. Try again

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines are perfect for this. Try this code here:

```cs
public Image image;
public Sprite[] sprites;
private bool isStop = true;

private void Start()
{
    isStop = false;
    StartCoroutine(Timer());
}

private IEnumerator Timer()
{
    while (!isStop)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sprites.Length; i++)
        {
            if (isStop) break;
            image.sprite = sprites[i];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's use case is to convert the actual time into a sprite. This would require a sprite for every second of the coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `float` to `int`

```
int spriteIndex = (int)Math.Round(timer);
```

And used `spriteIndex` as index to array sprites.
Or... if you need used different time interval for every sprite, you can make special struct for this animation.
For example:

```cs
[Serializable]
public struct SpriteFrame
{
    public Sprite FrameSprite;
    public float TimeToShow;
}

public class SpriteAnimationComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image ScoreCount; 
    public List<SpriteFrame> Frames = new List<SpriteFrame>();
    private int _currentFrame = 0;
    private float _currentPlayAnimationTime = 0f;

    private bool IsPlay => _currentFrame < Frames.Count;

    public void Start()
    {
        UpdateFrame();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if(!IsPlay)
            return;

        _currentPlayAnimationTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if(NeedShowNextFrame())
            ShowNextFrame();
    }

    private bool NeedShowNextFrame()
        => Frames[_currentFrame].TimeToShow < _currentPlayAnimationTime;

    private void ShowNextFrame()
    {
        _currentPlayAnimationTime -= Frames[_currentFrame].TimeToShow;
        _currentFrame++;
        if(IsPlay)
        {
            UpdateFrame();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateFrame()
    {
        ScoreCount.sprite = Frames[_currentFrame].FrameSprite;
    }
}
```

You need used SerializableAttribute (`[Serializable]`) on SpriteFrame for show struct in Unity Inspector. In current code animation show once, but you can make it loop. For loop animation just add `_currentFrame %= Frames.Count` after `_currentFrame++`